# Powershell XML Object not returned

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an xml which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<objects xmlns="http:www.springframework.net">

<object id="id1" type="1" method="1">    
   <property name="name" ref="serv1"/>    
</object>

<object id="id2" type="2" method="2">    
  <property name="name2" ref="serv2"/>    
</object>

</objects>
```

Now when i do this in power shell

```
$xmlFile=get-content $filename

$xmlFile.selectNodes("/objects/object[@id='id1']")
```

it does not return anything (returns null)

I need to modify the property value for one of the objects.
any help is welcome.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define that it is an XML object, so change the first line to:

```
[xml]$xmlfile = get-content $filename
```

That should solve your problem.